# Is it possible to call Kotlin from JavaScript via Graal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, kotlin, graalvm

This works

```
var NodeTransformerClass = Java.type('com.fispan.crypto.api.java.NodeTransformer');
var nodeTransformer = new NodeTransformerClass();
var result = nodeTransformer.protect(customer, specification);
```

but this

```
var KotlinTransformerClass = Java.type('com.fispan.crypto.api.kotlin.NodeTransformer');
var kotlinTransformer = new KotlinTransformerClass();
var kotlinResult = kotlinTransformer.protect(customer, specification);
```

produces

```
unknown:0
unknown
^

[Error: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics]
```

**Am I correct in assuming there is no way to call Kotlin directly from JavaScript/Node/js?**

Also if you call Node.js -> Java -> Kotlin, you get the same message.

**Am I correct in assuming there is no way to call into the JVM from Node.js if there is any Kotlin code in the call chain?** Would this also be true of Scala or any other JVM language?

If so, this makes GraalVM completely unsuitable to our needs?

See also https://github.com/oracle/graaljs/issues/484

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally figured this out... I did not have a complete JAR on my Graal Node `classpath`. Java was working because the Java runtime is automatically included, but the Kotlin runtime is not.

My solution was to use the Gradle `shadow` plugin to build a complete JAR. Once I did this, Node.js can call Java, and Java can call Kotlin.

See also fat-JAR and uber-JAR